# Python-Nuitka cannot compile .py to .exe with icon i've set

Tags: cmd, nuitka

Here I use windows10 cmd. I tried to compile .py to .exe with Nuitka lib and set my own icon to the future app. It worked perfectly without setting icon, but when I try to use:

```
python -m nuitka --mingw64 --windows-icon-from-ico=my/path/to/the/icon.ico my/path/to/executable/file.py
```

for compilation, I always catch an error, that says:

```
"FATAL:
Error, specify only one positional argument unless "--run" is specified to
pass them to the compiled program execution."
```

Comment: Hopefully you figured it out by now, but I'm guessing the actual `my/path/to/the/icon.ico` had a space in it. In which case it should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @MaximPaperno I've just not used an icon) But yeah, sure, an error could have been only because of space in a path(that time I had no idea how command string works) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Maxim Paperno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246449/maxim-paperno) noticed, such an error may occur when you have a path to an icon with a space(s) in it. When you have a space in a path and you use such a path in a terminal, then the part after the space is recognized by command string as another positional argument.

*P.S.* That's a really bad practice to use spaces in folder/file names, it can lead to unexpected errors anytime you work with such paths.